# undefined is not a function during ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 1 form per page and I've successfully testing this code on multiple occasions, but now for some reason, I keep getting this error:

> undefined is not a function

This posts my form values from my MVC View to the Controller and if there was an error processing

```
    $("form").submit(function () {
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            if (!data.IsOK) {
                $("#modalTitle").html(data.Title);
                $("#modalMessage").html(data.Message);
                $("#modalDetail").html(data.Error).hide(); // error occurs here
                $("#modalDialog").css("display", "block");
                $("#modalBackground").css("display", "block");
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = '@Url.Content("~/")';
            }
            return;
        });

        return false;
    });
```

The idea is to generate a modal dialog that tells the user "something went wrong" and provide information that can be used to track the issue. In many cases, though, the user won't get to see the `#modalDetail` div because that'll contain a stack trace (data.Error) which only sysadmin users should see.

I have a feeling like this error is happening if data.Error is blank but it just seems to me like the html for that div will only be set to an empty string value or equivalent.

Comment: Try a `console.log(data)` to make sure all variables are set.

Comment: `if (!data.IsOK) {` seems odd. I guess you want to populate data **if** `data.IsOK` is true, not false? With `if (!data.IsOK) {` you are sure that `data.Title` etc is undefined.

Comment: Looks like `data.Error` may not be defined. Also doing a `.hide()` does not prevent the user from seeing it. They can just look at the plain HTML, so if that is really private information that a user should not see. Don't even give that value back it it's not a sysadmin. Although my guess is that an error message isn't anything too important.

Answer (score 0):

You'll run into this error if `data.Error = undefined`

So to avoid this, do this

`$("#modalDetail").html(data.Error === undefined ? "" : data.Error).hide();`

This is just checking if the `Error` is undefined and adding empty string if it is.